# If Japan weren't an archipelago

Tags: alternate-reality

If Japan was connected by land to mainland Asia, would Japanese history be greatly affected? If so, in what ways? It would be nice to know these specific sectors of Japanese history and culture:

- Military history and technology
- Gastronomy
- Architecture
- Social attitudes

Time era is within 1300s until the start of the Meiji era (1868).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.  Please take the [tour] and poke through the [help], and browse the existing content to get a feel for the kinds of questions that are suitable here.

Comment: In every way from what they eat to the inhabitants.

Comment: Yes it would be greatly affected. It would be either part of a greater Korea or China. In what ways? Effectively it every way. This may sound facetious, but it's not. The changes would simply be that. Welcome to Worldbuilding, jehielLLMalan, your question about Japan needs to be more focused on a specific aspect of Japanese history to be answerable.

Comment: You still have four questions.  Please pick one.  Also, connected by land where?  South Korea?  Siberia?  China?

Comment: If Japan weren't an archipelago, it would be Korea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one thing, [Admiral Yi](https://youtu.be/3ieaDfD_h6s?list=PLILtKfUdIVd0HfXVeDVk154fFfYe4FN0h) may need not have bothered with defending Korea.

The fact that Japan is surrounded by deadly, deadly water has both helped them avoid invasions or forced invaders to use something they may not be great at- sailing. Such is the case of [Mongol invasions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_invasions_of_Japan).

I would wager that even a small isthmus connecting those islands the the mainland becomes the source of both profitable trade and devastating war. Japan's isolation has been important factor in history, and an isthmus would end that isolation.

I doubt Japan would have the chance to develop as it did with a mainland connection: it could be Mongol Islands.

Or maybe Japan would have succeed in taking a bite out of China and Korea, and the lands near the Sea of Japan and the Yellow Sea would *all* be Japan.

Hard to say more without a specific time-period.